# Определить HTTP или HTTPS PHP

Tags: php, веб-сервер, протоколы

Как с помощью PHP определить протокол (например, HTTP или HTTPS) url'а, на котором скрипт выполняется?

Comment: Советы ниже нужно помнить с двумя оговорками: есть такая вещь, как режим CLI и нужно сначала предварительно убедиться, что вы в нём не находитесь (почему-то никто про это не сказал). Кроме того, ваш сервер httpd может находиться за nginx и обращение к бекенду может идти по http, а наружу отдаваться уже как https (накладные расходы ненужные).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите в [`$_SERVER['HTTPS']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Для `IIS`, как обычно, особое исключение.

[Пример проверки](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1177) из `symfony`, поэтому должно быть достаточно проверки:

```
$isHttps = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && 'off' !== strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
```

Answer (score 2):

можно проверить использованием $_SERVER['HTTPS'] если пустой значит http

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
```

Comment: А если потом скрипт запустить из командной строки -- он будет думать, что выполняется на http?

Answer (score 2):

На разных серверах может и не быть $_SERVER['HTTPS']. Есть ещё $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]. Но их тоже может не быть. И ещё встречал ситуации, когда вообще ничего нет. В итоге гарантированно определить протокол не получится.

Comment: Ну, SERVER_PORT ничего не значит, а HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO можно подделать на некоторых серверах